# Code to update website asynchronously not working? Detailed description

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, ajax

Below are two Javascript functions that call a python file to update html. The top one works just fine, but the one on the bottom is not working. No errors thrown.

```js
function button(key) {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.open("GET", "example.py?keyword="+key, false);
  xhttp.send();
  var response = xhttp.responseText;
  var array = response.split('|');
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = array[0];
  document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = array[1];
}
function current(id) {
  var xhttp2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp2.open("GET", "example.py?infokey="+id, false);
  xhttp2.send();
  var response = xhttp2.responseText;
  document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = response;
}
```

I have debugged the python code extensively, and it is not the problem. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The second function is not working because you are trying to read the response before the response came from the server.

Try this:-

```
function current(id) {
  var xhttp2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp2.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
      var response = xhttp2.responseText;
      document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = response;
  }
  xhttp2.open("GET", "example.py?infokey="+id, false);
  xhttp2.send();
}
```